# IntelliJ how to add module to existing module

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I am trying to add new microservice in my project. I want it under Microservices module, but when I click Microservices -> add new module (loan-service) it appears over my Microservices module, but not nested inside it as a part of Microservices module. 
[image]

Even more in the left panel navigation this module is not showing. Is this the right way of doing things or am I missing anything

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you specify the correct content root (highlighted yellow and green) when [adding a module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#add-new-module).

You can also [group different modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#grouping-modules) in the Project Structure dialog without actually creating a parent module for them - the group will be visible in the Project tool window (red underlined).

[image]

[image]

[image]